# Calendar object returning 2016 when running instance for 2015

Tags: java, calendar

While I am Running the below code today(28 Dec 2015), I am getting a value 28 Dec 2016

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYYY").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

To double check i ran the following code

```
Calendar now =Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

It gives me year -  2015

What could be the reason?

Comment: `YYYY` should be `yyyy`.

Comment: With 2015 closing, this question seems to be one of the obvious duplicating one :)

Comment: Thanks ..... It Worked.. :)